# Getting Started with Neural Networks (ANN)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm, real-time-systems

I've been involved with a lot of C-Programming and RT-Linux, now I want to do some Artificial Neural Networking.

**BUT:** How do I get started?

I'm also very interested in Evolutionary Algorithms(Learning Algorithms) and Artificial Intelligence. Where can I start learning all of this?

Comment: There are lots of online courses. I have summarized some recent architectures on https://www.data-blogger.com/2017/02/26/artificial-neural-nets-a-gentle-introduction/.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're just trying to get familiar with AI, then I would recommend that you take the Stanford's free online courses:

- https://www.ai-class.com/
- http://www.ml-class.org/course/auth/welcome

Get a good understanding of the ML/AI concepts and play with the algorithms.

Additional links:

- Neural Network Example: http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/evolved/nnt1.html
- GP: http://www.genetic-programming.org/

There are many more resources online, but I think the above will give you a decent start. Also, there are a LOT of similar questions on SO that provide many useful links so I would recommend that you search for these topics on stackoverflow.com:

- Neural Networks on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/neural-network?sort=votes
- Genetic Algorithms on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic-algorithm
- Genetic Programming on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/genetic-programming
- Evolutionary Algos on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/evolutionary-algorithm

Comment: Does this involve both ANN and evolutionary algorithms?

Comment: I haven't personally taken the courses (too busy at work), but a co-worker of mine said that they do cover some neural network stuff. However, the class will give you a very broad introduction into ML/AI and you will learn about some libraries that have neural networks and genetic/evolutionary algorithms in them. If you want more hands-on examples of ANNs and GPs, then I will add a couple of links above. However, I would still recommend you take the classes first.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an all inclusive solution to get started with neural nets in python:

- Framework
- Written-to-be-read sources
- Live examples from data prep to training
- Documentation website literally tailored on the code and providing code/math/diagram/text side by side.

[epynn.net](https://epynn.net)